# Abort Windows initial configuration

Tags: windows-7

I accidentally started a computer which is pre-installed with Windows. A GUI with the title "Configure Windows" started a procedure which lets the user enter language, user name and other information in order to create a working windows installation.

**I would like to abort this procedure, and restore the computer to the state it was in before I switched in on. How can I do this?**

The GUI does not seem to offer a way to abort. There are no "Cancel" or "Abort" buttons.

Can I just switch the computer off (by holding down the power button) in the middle of this procedure? Would the computer start and be healthy again?

Comment: All you can do is power it off, it should start that dialog on the next startup.

Comment: @Moab: Okay, thanks. I take it that you have some kind of experience of information that indicates that is actually okay to power if off?

Comment: @Lii - Computers are designed to be turned off.  While turning off a computer running an OS, without allowing the OS to turn the computer off isn't good, it won't do any damage if done once.

Comment: @Ramhound: The thing is that the computer is in the middle of a configuration procedure... that *might* mess up things. But I think the chance is small enough to risk it.

Comment: [Sysprep (Generalize) a Windows installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn938334(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You never really started the configuration process, and your only choice is to power it down, yes I have done it on XP, Vista and W7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Experience report

I did switch off the computer (holding down the power button, just pressing the power button sent the computer into suspend mode).

**It does seem all right.** At least in that, when I started it again, the same configuration GUI appeared and no error messages.

During the boot the standard boot menu appeared which informed me that Windows did not terminate normally. But that's normal and should probably not be a problem in the future.

I was later able to complete the configuration and Windows seems to be working normally.